# Как к строке прибавить цифру, чтобы она увеличивалась в цикле

Tags: php

Должно выводится =>
block0, block1, block2, block3, block4

Но у меня не получается вывести задуманное.

Вот код:

```js
$a = "block";

for($b = 0; $b < 5; $b++){
echo $a = ($a + $b) ."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

конкатенация должна быть...

```
echo $a . $b ."<br>";
```

Comment: Сделал, но у меня не выходит задуманное то есть,  block0, block1, block2, block3, block4 вместо всего этого выходит block0
block0
1
block0
1
2
block0
1
2
3
block0
1
2
3
4

Comment: да, без `$a = `  надо